# Tkinter Widgets next to each other and below

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm putting widgets into a popup for my GUI. I'm putting the checkboxes along the top of the pop up and I want the label, entry and button to be in a row below them. Whatever I try the label, entry and button always go next to the check boxes. I haven't found a solution which uses `pack()`. I've tried `anchor=`but this also didn't do what I wanted.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()


    class PopUp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            popup = tk.Toplevel(self, background='gray15')
            popup.wm_title("EMAIL")
            self.withdraw()
            popup.tkraise(self)
            self.c1 = tk.Checkbutton(popup, text="Current", variable=CheckVar1, onvalue =1, offvalue = 0, height=2, width=15)
            self.c1.pack(side="left", fill="x")
            self.c2 = tk.Checkbutton(popup, text="-1", variable=CheckVar2, onvalue =1, offvalue = 0, height=2, width=15)
            self.c2.pack(side="left", fill="x")
            label = tk.Label(popup, text="Please Enter Email Address", background='gray15', foreground='snow')
            label.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
            self.entry = tk.Entry(popup, bd=5, width=35, background='gray30', foreground='snow')
            self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="x")
            self.button = tk.Button(popup, text="OK", command=self.on_button, background='gray15', foreground='snow')
            self.button.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        def on_button(self):
            address = self.entry.get() 
            print(address)
            time.sleep(10)
            self.destroy()


    app = PopUp()
    app.mainloop
```

Is there something I can put into `pack()` so that I can put the widgets next to each other and then put the other below them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider to use [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the grid geometry manager to divide your window into two frames, then pack your widgets into the frames.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class PopUp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        CheckVar1 = IntVar()
        CheckVar2 = IntVar()
        popup = Toplevel(self, background='gray15')
        popup.wm_title("EMAIL")
        self.withdraw()
        popup.tkraise(self)

        topframe = Frame(popup)
        topframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

        bottomframe = Frame(popup)
        bottomframe.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.c1 = Checkbutton(topframe, text="Current", variable=CheckVar1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2, width=15)
        self.c1.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        self.c2 = Checkbutton(topframe, text="-1", variable=CheckVar2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2, width=15)

        self.c2.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        label = Label(bottomframe, text="Please Enter Email Address", background='gray15', foreground='snow')
        label.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
        self.entry = Entry(bottomframe, bd=5, width=35, background='gray30', foreground='snow')
        self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        self.button = Button(bottomframe, text="OK", command=self.on_button, background='gray15', foreground='snow')
        self.button.pack(side="left", padx=10)

    def on_button(self):
        address = self.entry.get()
        print(address)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.destroy()


app = PopUp()
app.mainloop()
```

A few notes:

1. There is no need to import Tkinter twice
2. Mainloop is a method, so it's app.mainloop()
3. CheckVar1 and CheckVar2 must be declared within your class
4. camel case (capitalising within words, e.g 'CheckVar') is not pythonic

Comment: This worked great, however, I can't set the bg of the bottom frame, I can set the colour of the top frame by including the background color in tk.Checkbutton() but this does not work for the bottom frame. Any ideas?

Comment: It's as simple as specifying the background when creating the frames, so `bottomframe = Frame(popup, bg="blue")`